# nuget packaging referenced assemblies in the solution

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a visual studio solution with the following structure

```
Project 1
   Reference Projec2
   Reference Projec3
Project 2
Project 3
```

All above are .NET 4 projects. I am trying to create a nuget package for Project 1, however using the default nuspec file, the package does not include the project2 and 3 assemblies in the net40 folder. Please note that I do not want to create separate packages for project2 and 3 as these assemblies are only ever used by Project 1.

To get around this, I am doing something like this

```
  <files>    
    <file src="bin\release\*.dll" target="lib\net40"                           
          exclude="**\Project1.dll"  />
  </files>
```

I was wondering if the above is the best solution?

Also for the Symbol package, it does not include .pdb files for Project 2 and 3?

I have also noticed that on the nuget [website](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference) it says that

> if you specify any files, the conventions are ignored and only the
>   files listed in the .nuspec file are included in the package.

I don't see the above happening because when i use the  element, i still get the Project1 assembly in the lib folder by convention, therefore I had to exclude it otherwise nuget throws exception that the file already exists.Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason for Project1, 2 and 3 to be separate (and you say that 2 and 3 are only ever used by 1), merge them into one project. You can separate concerns also by adding folders inside one project. For instance, for a typical MVVM-based WPF project I would have

```
MyProject
[ ]Properties -> contains AssemblyInfo.cs
[ ]Resources -> contains resources
[ ]Model -> contains Model classes
[ ]ViewModel -> contains ViewModel classes
[ ]View -> contains View classes
[ ]App -> contains App.xaml etc.
```

Etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple assemblies (and PDBs) to your package, however, you will have to list them, as wildcards don't work (at least they didn't last time I tried).

Or you could automate the creation of the nuspec (and nupkg) file using a solution like this:

Add my utility, `NuGetPack.exe` and the standard `NuGet.exe` to your solution folder and the solution, then add a new class library project to your solution, reference the projects you want to package, then add a post build event to the new project and build.

You can find an article with a [walk-through guide here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/804005/) and the [source code + binary here](https://pubcomp.codeplex.com/).